# Does P4 preserve file history of a copied/integrated file whose integration source is deleted?

Tags: directory, version-control, perforce, directory-structure, perforce-stream

For example, there is a file in my Perforce depot at `//my_depot/my_stream/my_folder/file.txt`, which has a long revision history. Due to a refactor, the file is then copied (integrated) to `//my_depot/different_stream/another_folder/file.txt`. This keeps the revision history by keeping a reference to the original file as its "branch from" integration source.

What happens if the original location of the file (in this case, the entire `my_stream` stream) is deleted? Does the file's revision history remain accessible from the P4 server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a file is "deleted" in Perforce, a new revision with the action `delete` is submitted on top of the existing revisions.  Old revisions remain exactly where they are, old integration history referencing those revisions remains valid, et cetera.

When a stream is deleted, the stream spec is gone, *but* the depot files that were part of the stream aren't affected in any way, so again, history remains accessible.  You can still reference the files by their depot path, and old integration history still points to them.

When a file is *obliterated*, its history is gone forever.  Only an admin can obliterate files, and this is something that should only be done when history is no longer important (or never at all).

Comment: OK, thank you for the explanation! It's good to know it's safe to delete the stream. Do the files from it reside in the depot under a subdirectory? All the paths resemble `//my_depot/stream_name/...`. For example, if I delete the stream, and want to get it back, is it enough to point a new stream to the same depot path?

Comment: A stream can potentially have a more complicated path specification than that.  Set up a spec depot (just make a depot whose type is `spec`) and all your specs are backed up there, which makes it possible to restore (e.g.) a stream spec by doing `p4 print -q //spec/stream/your_stream.p4s#N | p4 stream -i`

Comment: Will look into this, was not aware. Thank you.